# input from command-line argument works, but input from internal char* gives Bus Error. Shouldn't it be identical?

Tags: c, bus

I wrote a function that will take a `char*` representing a binary number, and add one to that number. I've encountered a very confusing error, which is that the function works fine and dandy when the `char*` comes from user input when calling the function (a.k.a. `argv[1]`), but gives me a `Bus error: 10` when I instead initialize the variable internally and pass it to the same function. I'm not sure what's behind this, so I turn to you guys. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void addOneBinaryMain(char* strBiNum, int index)
{
    if (strBiNum[index] == '0' || index == 0) { //BUS ERROR OCCURS HERE
        strBiNum[index] = '1';
        return;
    } else {
        strBiNum[index] = '0';
        addOneBinaryMain(strBiNum, index - 1);
    }
}

void addOneBinary(char* strBiNum)
{
    addOneBinaryMain(strBiNum, strlen(strBiNum)-1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* str = argv[1];
    char* strZero = "00000000";
    int i;

    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%s\n", strZero);

    addOneBinary(str);
    printf("added one to input string: %s\n", str); //succeeds
    addOneBinary(strZero);
    printf("added one to internal zero string: %s\n", strZero);

    return 0;
}
```

Following around the error with print statements, it seems that it occurs in the `addOneBinaryMain` function (the recursive step), at the point I've marked.

Answer (score 1):

`strZero` points at a constant string, that cannot be changed

Comment: Even though I didn't type `const char*`? So is the only way around this is to initialize it with `malloc()` and iteratively assign each value? seems like a PITA, but I suppose if it's the only way it works...

Comment: Yes, this array can be allocated in a constant section of process, so any attempt to change it is denied by system. Try char strZero[] = "0000" instead

Answer (score 1):

strZero is just a point initialized with the address of your literal string "000000". This literal string is stored at a place in the application's ram that is read only (If i remember correctly think it's called **static store**).

Try declaring a char array on the stack or on the heap and copying strZero to it using strcpy.

Comment: You welcome,
Btw, I think there is a a bug in your code, when the binary number overflows (trying to add 1 to 111 to get 000) you will get 100 instead.